# Using `dig` Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to look up the IPv4 address (a single one, which I will `assert` on!) for a given name using Ansible and use that as a fact "down the line".

An MWE looks like this:

```
---
# vim: set autoindent smartindent tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 expandtab filetype=ansible:

- name: Preparations
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    host2lookup: "example.com"
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: ahostsv4
        key: "{{host2lookup}}"
    - debug:
        var: getent_ahostsv4
    - name: Lookup for {{host2lookup}}
      debug:
        msg: "{{lookup('dig', '{{host2lookup}}./A')}}"
```

... and fails as follows (relevant excerpt):

```
  localhost failed | msg: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dig'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The dig lookup requires the python 'dnspython' library and it is not installed
```

So I thought to myself I'd install the `dnspython` library for the appropriate Python version, making the playbook look as follows:

```
---
# vim: set autoindent smartindent tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 expandtab filetype=ansible:

- name: Preparing Ansible host
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Install dnspython package on Ansible host
      block:
        - name: Installing python-dnspython package
          apt:
            pkg:
              - python-dnspython
            update_cache: yes
            install_recommends: no
            state: present
          when: ansible_python.version.major == 2
        - name: Installing python3-dnspython package
          apt:
            pkg:
              - python3-dnspython
            update_cache: yes
            install_recommends: no
            state: present
          when: ansible_python.version.major == 3
      become: true
- name: Preparations
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    host2lookup: "example.com"
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: ahostsv4
        key: "{{host2lookup}}"
    - debug:
        var: getent_ahostsv4
    - name: Lookup for {{host2lookup}}
      debug:
        msg: "{{lookup('dig', '{{host2lookup}}./A')}}"
```

But the ultimate failure remains the same. Either that error is misleading or something else is fishy ...

```
Executing playbook dbg.yml

- Preparing Ansible host on hosts: localhost -
Gathering Facts...
  localhost ok
Installing python-dnspython package...
Installing python3-dnspython package...
  localhost ok

- Preparations on hosts: localhost -
Gathering Facts...
  localhost ok
getent...
  localhost ok
debug...
  localhost ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "getent_ahostsv4": {
        "93.184.216.34": [
            "RAW"
        ]
    }
}
Lookup for example.com...
  localhost failed | msg: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dig'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The dig lookup requires the python 'dnspython' library and it is not installed

- Play recap -
  localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What other than the appropriate `dnspython` package am I missing here?

---

The `dnsutils` package (containing `dig`) and its library dependencies is installed. Adding these as prerequisites into the `apt:` task therefore makes no difference.

Found another smoking gun, though:

```
$ python3 -m dnspython
/usr/bin/python3: No module named dnspython
$ sudo -H pip3 install dnspython
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

I stand corrected. As per the [examples page](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html) I should import something like `dns.query` (`python3 -m dns.query`). And that succeeds.

My `ansible.cfg` is this:

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
nocows = true
command_warnings = false
stdout_callback = unixy
display_skipped_hosts = false
interpreter_python=auto
```

The whole thing runs on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

As per request in a comment, I am providing more output. This is still on Ubuntu 18.04. With the (above shown) `ansible.cfg` in place, I get the following output:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_python*'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python2",
            "has_sslcontext": true,
            "type": "CPython",
            "version": {
                "major": 2,
                "micro": 17,
                "minor": 7,
                "releaselevel": "final",
                "serial": 0
            },
            "version_info": [
                2,
                7,
                17,
                "final",
                0
            ]
        },
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.17"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

However, `ansible-playbook` behaves differently here. Consider the following playbook:

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_python
    - debug:
        var: ansible_python_version
```

The output becomes:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local dbg.yml
Executing playbook dbg.yml

- all on hosts: all -
Gathering Facts...
  localhost ok
debug...
  localhost ok: {
    "ansible_python": {
        "executable": "/usr/bin/python3",
        "has_sslcontext": true,
        "type": "cpython",
        "version": {
            "major": 3,
            "micro": 9,
            "minor": 6,
            "releaselevel": "final",
            "serial": 0
        },
        "version_info": [
            3,
            6,
            9,
            "final",
            0
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
debug...
  localhost ok: {
    "ansible_python_version": "3.6.9",
    "changed": false
}

- Play recap -
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

... **comment out the following line** from `ansible.cfg`:

```
interpreter_python=auto
```

... and the output (when rerunning the previous command) becomes:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local dbg.yml
Executing playbook dbg.yml

- all on hosts: all -
Gathering Facts...
  localhost ok
debug...
  localhost ok: {
    "ansible_python": {
        "executable": "/usr/bin/python",
        "has_sslcontext": true,
        "type": "CPython",
        "version": {
            "major": 2,
            "micro": 17,
            "minor": 7,
            "releaselevel": "final",
            "serial": 0
        },
        "version_info": [
            2,
            7,
            17,
            "final",
            0
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
debug...
  localhost ok: {
    "ansible_python_version": "2.7.17",
    "changed": false
}

- Play recap -
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Nothing [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) suggests that this should happen.

Comment: Update the question and add the output of the command `ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_python_version`

Comment: @VladimirBotka I _honestly_ appreciate your effort, but what does the `ansible` command line tool have to do with behavior I see with `ansible-playbook`? I will amend the question shortly. You'll notice that the two tools behave differently in this exact case. No clue why, but it can be reproduced.

Comment: @VladimirBotka amended the question with requested information ... and a little more, since the information you requested isn't representative of the issue I am encountering.

Comment: You did not amend the question with the requested information. I asked you to use `-hosts: localhost`, but you used `- hosts: all`. This is really `little more`.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Huh? Which part of `ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_python*'` (other than using a filter instead of `grep`) _lacks_ the requested information? Your request was for output from `ansible` and I pointed out the discrepancy with that of `ansible-playbook` based on the `interpreter_python=auto` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- [Ansible is using the wrong version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257164/ansible-is-using-wrong-version-of-python)
- [How can I specify the version of Python to use in an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450608/how-can-i-specify-the-version-of-python-to-use-in-an-ansible-playbook)
- [How to choose Python interpreter for Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380824/how-to-choose-a-python-interpreter-for-ansible-playbook)

See also [Setting the Python interpreter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/intro_bsd.html#setting-the-python-interpreter) that explains various configurations' options, variables, and debugging.

---

Q: ***"None of that explains why - and that is/was my point - **ansible_python wrongly claims to be running on Python 3.x on the local node**. Because all I do by setting **interpreter_python** in ansible.cfg is to give Ansible free rein on how it interprets things."***

Short answer: You can't configure the version of Python the Ansible utils use ($ ansible --version). [INTERPRETER_PYTHON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) configures the Python version used by the Ansible modules on the remote hosts.

A: Configuration option INTERPRETER_PYTHON works as expected. There is nothing wrong when Python3 is discovered when asked by `interpreter_python=auto`.

- [auto](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) (default)

See implementation details of the function [discover_interpreter](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/interpreter_discovery.py). When the version of the distro is not in [_INTERPRETER_PYTHON_DISTRO_MAP](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/config/base.yml)

> *"return nearest previous version we're newer than"*

```py
def _version_fuzzy_match(version, version_map):
...
    # slot match; return nearest previous version we're newer than
    kpos = bisect.bisect(sorted_looseversions, find_looseversion)
```

```ini
interpreter_python=auto
```

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_python_version'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_python_version": "3.7.3", 
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

- [auto_legacy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) (default is */usr/bin/python*)

> *"The default value of **auto_legacy** provides all the same behavior, but for backward compatibility with older Ansible releases that always defaulted to **/usr/bin/python**, will use that interpreter if present (and issue a warning that the default behavior will change to that of auto in a future Ansible release."*

```ini
interpreter_python=auto_legacy
```

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_python_version'
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 19.04 on host localhost should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future
 Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more 
information. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.16", 
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

See the notes and examples below.

---

Q: ***"What does the ansible command line tool have to do with the behavior I see with ansible-playbook?"***

A: Both ansible command line tool and ansible-playbook will report the same value of *ansible_python_version*. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup | grep ansible_python_version
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.16",
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_python_version
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_python_version": "2.7.16"
}
```

---

Notes

1. [INTERPRETER_PYTHON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) configuration parameter says:

> Path to the Python interpreter to be used for module execution **on remote targets**

See [How to choose a python interpreter for Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380824/how-to-choose-a-python-interpreter-for-ansible-playbook/)

2. Ansible will tell what Python is used **on master**

```bash
shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.9.2
  config file = /home/vlado/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/vlado/.ansible/my_modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:36:04) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

3. [dig](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html#dig-query-dns-using-the-dnspython-library) says

> The below requirements are needed **on the local master node** that executes this lookup: dnspython

4. It's possible to install both versions

```bash
shell> dpkg -l | grep dnspython
ii  python-dnspython         1.16.0-1 all          DNS toolkit for Python
ii  python3-dnspython        1.16.0-1 all          DNS toolkit for Python 3
```

5. See [Ansible packages in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ansible) what version of Python was used.
6. [ansible_python_interpreter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) works as expected

**On master(Ubuntu) the playbook**

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: hosts
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_01 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -vvv | grep python
```

gives

> ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
> **python version = 2.7.16** (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:36:04) [GCC 8.3.0]

...

> <test_01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/export/home/vlado.config/.ansible/cp/5a3ab05cf7 -tt test_01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-xnvwkdksdqqoehvrgebdgcnrzcrmoszv ; **/usr/local/bin/python3.6** /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1576667662.62-67468482045094/AnsiballZ_getent.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

- ansible-playbook **on master** runs with `python version = 2.7.16`
- module **on remote** (test_01) runs with `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`

**Change ansible_python_interpreter**

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_01 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

the same playbook gives

> ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
> **python version = 2.7.16** (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:36:04) [GCC 8.3.0]

...

> <test_01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/export/home/vlado.config/.ansible/cp/5a3ab05cf7 -tt test_01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-fidpgwptggdoizirumvjmzuorxqawypu ; **/usr/local/bin/python2.7** /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1576668475.22-210929624017605/AnsiballZ_getent.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

- ansible-playbook **on master** runs with `python version = 2.7.16`
- but module **on remote** (test_01) runs with `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` as requested

Comment: Yes, but _none_ of that explains why - and _that_ is/was my point - `ansible_python` wrongly claims to be running on Python 3.x on the _local node_. Because all I do by setting `interpreter_python` in `ansible.cfg` is to give Ansible free rein on how it interprets things. But since I am depending on its choices and its information being consistent (which it evidently isn't), things blow up in my face. Regarding point 4, it's completely beside the point, because I am attempting to install the appropriate version _based on_ `ansible_python`, but Ansible simply lies to me ...

Comment: There is no evidence that *`ansible_python wrongly claims to be running on Python 3.x on the local node`*. I've added more details that might help to clarify the situation.

Comment: The evidence is the behavior one gets _with_ `when:` ... the wrong package that gets installed (provided _neither_, i.e. `python-dnspython`/`python3-dnspython`, was installed before). This is actually reproducible. But you're right, this only happens with `interpreter_python=auto` set in `ansible.cfg` for me. But then I consistently see it (and I have actually used the `debug` module to verify the value of `ansible_python` is wrong). Only if `python-dnspython` is preinstalled (`samba` installs it, for example) don't I see the issue. Otherwise I can reproduce on all 18.04 so far.

Comment: Just to make sure. I understand that the lookup plugins get called on the control/master. In my real-world case the `Preparing Ansible host` part is getting actually executed on the control/master, but the `Preparations` part gets executed on the remote machine(s). With the sole exception of the loopkup plugin, so I understand that the `dnspython` package needs to be installed on control/master and that the _result_ of the lookup is passed (by value) to the remote machine(s). In my MWE I had to condense this for obvious reasons.

Comment: _A: Both ansible command line tool and ansible-playbook will report the same value of **ansible_python_version**._ ... unfortunately not true, at least not unconditionally (see amendments to the question).

Comment: When executing "remotely" on the control host, Ansible uses the logic used for remote hosts when determining which Python to use for execution. The Python it was started with may not be the same.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka: This is where I ended up now. StackExchange questions and answers are supposed to be useful to anyone who finds them, so they must be kept up to date.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is there anything, in particular, you can't find?

Answer (score 1):

Since this confused the hell out of me and cost me about an hour to figure out, I am going to post an answer.

As you can see I am using `ansible_python` to determine the Python version and install the appropriate version of `dnspython`. Since this is on Ubuntu 18.04 it defaults to `python3`. I am suppressing the respective warning with `interpreter_python=auto` in the `ansible.cfg` inside the same folder.

But here's the bummer. Apparently `connection: local` somehow violates the rule about using `python3` whose `dnspython` package is installed. It made sense once I looked for `dig.py` (hoping for the [Ansible lookup module of the same name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html)). And indeed I found it:

```
$ locate dig.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/lookup/dig.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/lookup/dig.pyc
```

... alas, this means my version of Ansible uses Python 2.7 and so the `dig` module won't be able to make use of the `python3-dnspython` (Debian) package which I installed.

Still puzzling. But with the cause determined, I can work around it now.

Answer (score 0):

In ansible, `lookup`'s are [executed locally](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) where ansible runs, not on the target server.

So you will have to ensure that `dnspython` is installed on your ansible machine.